# Resolving nested data in express GraphQL

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I am currently trying to resolve a simple recipe list that has a reference to ingredients.

The data layout looks like this:

```
type Ingredient {
  name: String!
  amount: Int!
  unit: Unit!
  recipe: Recipe
}

type Recipe {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  ingredients: [Ingredient]!
  steps: [String]!
  pictureUrl: String!
}
```

As I understand it, my resolvers should look like this:
The first one resolves the recipes and second one resolves the ingredient field in the recipe. It can (from my understanding) use the argument provided by recipe. In my recipe object, the ingredient is referenced by id (int), so this should be the argument (at least that's what I think).

```
var root = {
  recipe: (argument) => {
       return recipeList;
  },
  Recipe: {
    ingredients: (obj, args, context) => {
        //resolve ingredients
    }
  },
```

These resolvers are passed to the app like this:

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  graphiql: true,
  rootValue: root,
}));
```

However, my resolver does not seem to be called. I would like the ingredients to be resolved on the fly when queried in my query.

The endpoint works, but as soon as I query for ingredients, an error with this message `"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Ingredient.name.",` is returned.

When trying to log the incoming arguments in my resolver, I can see that it is never executed. Unfortunately, I can't find examples on how to do this with express-graphql when using it like I am.

**How do I write seperate resolvers for nested types in express-graphQL?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only resolvers for queries and mutations can be defined through `root`, and even then this is bad practice. I'm guessing you're building your schema using `buildSchema`, which is generally a bad idea since [the generated schema will only use default resolvers](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#buildschema).

The only way to define resolvers for a field like `ingredients` when using plain GraphQL.js is to not use `buildSchema`. Instead of generating your schema from a string, you would define it programatically (i.e. defining a GraphQLSchema and all the types it uses).

Doing the above is a huge pain, especially if you already have your schema defined in a string or document. So the alternative option is to use graphql-tools' [makeExecutableSchema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html), which lets you inject those resolvers into your type definitions like you're trying to do. `makeExecutableSchema` returns a GraphQLSchema object, so you can use it with your existing code (you don't have to change your middleware to apollo-server if you don't want to).

Comment: Thank you so much! I used makeExecutableSchema, defined a custom resolver for Ingredient type and it worked instantly. I really found it hard to figure out what caused this, so thanks for explaining!

Comment: TBH I wasn't even aware that it's possible to build the schema programatically - every tutorial shows this `buildSchema` from string method. Why did they even create option to build it from string?